# linear combinatorial optimization

Tags: ruby, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

Am trying to figure out algorithms better than brute force to solve this combinatorial optimization.

Sample problem:
To achieve 2a+b at the minimum/maximum cost combining available linear equations
1. 2a+b =4
2. a =1
3. a+b =2
(RHS is cost)

Answer: Combine 2 and 3 to get 2a+b =3

The brute force method of finding the powerset (all combinations) of component linear equation, obviously is not optimal when target equation is lengthier and the powerset grows gigantic.

Is the problem a variant of Knapsack problem?
Any pointers on who this could be done optimally?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not Knapsack. It's just a linear optimization ([linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Example_2)) problem. For Ruby, you can use [RGLPK](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rglpk/)

Comment: Thanks Diego. Looking into RGLPK. Any pointers on how I could approach this specific problem with a better solution? Someone on SO suggested brand-out and back method to solve it. What's your opinion?

Comment: Do you mean *branch-out and back*? That sounds like a exploring a tree-like space, not sure if that'd be a brute-force approach though.

Comment: Yes its ultimately brute force. Just better than finding all combinations and then choosing.. Am considering a recursive approach :-)

Comment: It seems you might need integer programming (which is NP-complete) to get the optimal solution, since you can only have an integral amount of each equation.

Comment: Can you use each equation just once (since you say poweset) or multiple times?

Comment: @Diego I don't think these are linear equations. The OP is adding them up like simple units, not finding their intersection.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be formulated using linear programming. You can use the Gnu Linear Programming Kit (GLPK) and its Ruby wrapper 'rglpk' to solve it.

Download GLPK 4.44 from http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/ for your operating system. Unzip the package and install the application using the following command.

```
./configure && sudo make clean && sudo make && sudo make install
```

Open the command line and install 'rglpk' with the command below.

```
gem install rglpk
```

Run this code.

```
require 'rglpk'

#min/max 2a+b
#1. 2a+b=4 
#2. a=1 
#3. a+b=2

p = Rglpk::Problem.new
p.name = "sample"
p.obj.dir = Rglpk::GLP_MAX

rows = p.add_rows(3)
rows[0].name = "2a+b=4"
rows[0].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_UP, 0, 4)
rows[1].name = "a=1"
rows[1].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_UP, 0, 1)
rows[2].name = "a+b=2"
rows[2].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_UP, 0, 2)

cols = p.add_cols(2)
cols[0].name = "a"
cols[0].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0)
cols[1].name = "b"
cols[1].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0)

p.obj.coefs = [2, 1]

p.set_matrix([
2, 1,
1, 0,
1, 1
])

p.simplex
z = p.obj.get
x1 = cols[0].get_prim
x2 = cols[1].get_prim

printf("z = %g; x1 = %g; x2 = %g\n", z, x1, x2)
#=> z = 3; x1 = 1; x2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, it *is* a variant of the Knapsack problem. Each box has some apples and some bananas. It also has a cost. You have to pick some boxes to get a certain number of apples and bananas, minimizing the total cost.

I would use the DP Knapsack algorithm with a 2D cache instead of a 1D cache: cache[5][10] is how much it costs to get 5 apples and 10 bananas.

For each box, attempt to add it to all the configurations found so far and see if the result is cheaper than the cached value. It it is, update the cache.

Since the cache is going to be sparse, I'd use a set to keep track of the known configurations (ie the location of non-infinity cache values) so that looping over all the known configurations can be done without going through the entire cache.